# SQL-How to split multiple items from 1 row to multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on creating a report that will tell me how many emails are assigned to a report subscription , for example a report called "Monthly Customer Activity - Default Setup" can have 2 email subscriptions and each subscription can have different email addresses , lets say 5 emails each subscription , at the end my report will display on one column 10 times the report Name and on the other column the 10 email addresses.

I'm working using the code below and is working most of the time but on some  rows is not doing the email split . I'm using SQL Management Studio 2016 and I'm connecting to my SSRS 2016 Database

```
Use [ReportServer]
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
drop table #Temp

select
c.Name,
-- 'two' as OtherID,
Convert(XML,[ExtensionSettings]).value('(//ParameterValue/Value[../Name="TO"])[1]','nvarchar(max)') as email
INTO #Temp
FROM 
 dbo.[Catalog] c
INNER JOIN dbo.[Subscriptions] S ON c.ItemID = S.Report_OID
INNER JOIN dbo.ReportSchedule R ON S.SubscriptionID = R.SubscriptionID
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs J ON Convert(nvarchar(128),R.ScheduleID) = J.name
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules JS ON J.job_id = JS.job_id

;
WITH tmp(/*SomeID, OtherID,*/ Name, email,string) AS
(
    SELECT
        Name,
        --OtherID,
        LEFT(email, CHARINDEX(';', email + ';') - 1),
        STUFF(email, 1, CHARINDEX(';', email + ';'), '')
    FROM  #Temp

    UNION all

    SELECT
        Name,
        --OtherID,
        LEFT(email, CHARINDEX(';', email + ';') - 1),
        STUFF(email, 1, CHARINDEX(';', email + ';'), '')
    FROM tmp
    WHERE
        email != email
      and email is not NULL
)


select * from #Temp
order by email
```

The desired results will be:
https://imggmi.com/full/2019/1/17/a528cf472a96f5d2eff2759413b79814-full.png.html

Results I'm getting:

https://imggmi.com/full/2019/1/17/4ae835b3a877ad015af10372cf7f82e9-full.png.html

As you can see on the picture , is doing the split email on some rows but some others are still showing the emails together

Below is a sample test:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL drop table #Temp
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(Name varchar (50) , LastStatus varchar (max) , IBOAccount varchar (10) , Email varchar (max))
GO
INSERT INTO #Temp
Select 'Report A','Email sent to Email1@email.com','47213','Email1@email.com' UNION ALL
Select 'Report A','Email sent to Email100@email.com','13983','Email100@email.com' UNION ALL
Select 'Report A','Email sent to Email101@email.com','437707','Email101@email.com' UNION ALL
Select 'Report B','Email sent to Email103@email.com','NULL','Email103@email.com' UNION ALL
Select 'Report C','Email sent to Email110@email.com','NULL','Email110@email.com' UNION ALL
Select 'Report C','Email sent to Email128@email.com','NULL','Email128@email.com' UNION ALL
Select 'Report C','Email sent to Email2@email.com;Email3@email.com','170891','Email2@email.com;Email3@email.com' UNION ALL
Select 'Report D','Done: 1 processed of 1 total; 0 errors.','NULL','Email200@email.com;Email5000@email.com;Email1000@email.com;Email_001@email.com'
GO
```

Comment: Where is some sample data?

Comment: Since you are on 2016, I would suggest looking into string_split().  Or perhaps supply a small data sample and desired results

Comment: John , the Database server is 2008 , only the management studio is 2016 . I've tried to use that function and I've got  ""Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'.""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here i made those changes based on your data you provided

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL drop table #Temp
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(Name varchar (50) , LastStatus varchar (max) , IBOAccount varchar (10) , Email varchar (max))
GO
INSERT INTO #Temp
Select 'Report A','Email sent to Email1@email.com','47213','Email1@email.com' UNION ALL
Select 'Report A','Email sent to Email100@email.com','13983','Email100@email.com' UNION ALL
Select 'Report A','Email sent to Email101@email.com','437707','Email101@email.com' UNION ALL
Select 'Report B','Email sent to Email103@email.com','NULL','Email103@email.com' UNION ALL
Select 'Report C','Email sent to Email110@email.com','NULL','Email110@email.com' UNION ALL
Select 'Report C','Email sent to Email128@email.com','NULL','Email128@email.com' UNION ALL
Select 'Report C','Email sent to Email2@email.com;Email3@email.com','170891','Email2@email.com;Email3@email.com' UNION ALL
Select 'Report D','Done: 1 processed of 1 total; 0 errors.','NULL','Email200@email.com;Email5000@email.com;Email1000@email.com;Email_001@email.com'
GO;

declare  @result table (Name  nvarchar(max), email  varchar(MAX) )
while (select count(*) from #Temp)>0 
 begin
 declare @email varchar(max) = (select top 1 email from #temp)
 declare @Name varchar(max) = (select top 1 Name from #Temp)
 delete top (1) from #Temp where Name = @Name;
  IF RIGHT(@email, 1) <> ';'
    SELECT @email = @email + ';'

    DECLARE @Pos    BIGINT,
            @OldPos BIGINT
    SELECT  @Pos    = 1,
            @OldPos = 1

    WHILE   @Pos < LEN(@email)
        BEGIN
            SELECT  @Pos = CHARINDEX(';', @email, @OldPos)
            INSERT INTO @result (name , email)
            SELECT @Name, LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@email, @OldPos, @Pos - @OldPos))) email

            SELECT  @OldPos = @Pos + 1
        END

 end 

select * from @result
```

result:

```
Name    email
Report A    Email1@email.com
Report A    Email100@email.com
Report A    Email101@email.com
Report B    Email103@email.com
Report C    Email110@email.com
Report C    Email128@email.com
Report C    Email2@email.com
Report C    Email3@email.com
Report D    Email200@email.com
Report D    Email5000@email.com
Report D    Email1000@email.com
Report D    Email_001@email.com
```

Comment: Ale , I've added a sample test data based on the real data

Comment: Thank you , I'm still trying to figure out how to add the other 2 columns to the final results but your script does what I needed . Thank you so much and awesome code :)